# analysis of one example in shortest path tree

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

Consider connected and undirected Graph $G$.

shortest path tree for each vertexes of $G$ was given.

if we makes union of all these shortest path trees then  order (number)  of edges in this union at worst case is $O(n^2)$ !!

> how this achieved? is there any idea?

My Idea:

I think a complete graph with $n$ vertex, each vertex has shortest path tree at most of $n-1$ edges in worst case and then $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Your idea is exactly right. More formally:

- We have a shortest path tree $T_v$ for each vertex $v \in G$.
- Each $T_v$ is a tree, and has $n$ vertices (since $G$ is connected).
- This means each $T_v$ has $n-1$ edges.
- So we have $n$ choices of $v$, and $n-1$ edges in each $T_v$
- So the total number of edges in all the trees is $n \cdot (n-1)$.
- but this is $n^2 -n$, which is $O(n^2)$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^